# Should I go to synagogue when I can't focus?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, choleh-sick, kavana-concentration

If I am too ill/stressed to be able to concentrate on worshipping G-d, should I still go to synagogue? Is there an official ruling on this? I'm worried that I might be disrespecting G-d by going.

Comment: The gemoro says if someone ship has sunk at sea it is no excuse not to daven. I wonder if your illness/distress is as bad as that.

Comment: once asked Rabbi Zev Leff that if one is too tired/stressed to go daven and if he goes, he will be tired all day. is it better to daven at home? he answered to go daven in a minyan and try to sleep a bit after. end quote. usually its yetzer hara trying to get a step over you to get you on higher ground

Comment: @annex It also says you are patur for three days after traveling because you can't concentrate yet.